# I married a US citizen and then came back to the UK, can I re-enter the US on an F-1 student visa?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, study, residency, weddings

I visited Spokane WA in December 2016 and got married there to a US citizen. Then I returned to the UK to sort out finances while awaiting a spousal visa.

I felt I needed more direction in life so I started looking at college courses in Spokane and have set my heart on one.

Will my marriage affect my ability to use an F-1 visa and then adjust my status to permanent residency when my studies are completed?

Comment: You might even likely have committed immigration fraud through [preconceived intent](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/err/H5%20-%20Waiver%20of%20Inadmissibility%20-%20Misrepresentation%20-%20212%20(i)/Decisions_Issued_in_2012/Dec202012_07H5212.pdf) by going to Spokane to marry a citizen but that is another matter for your interviewer to decide. Immigration can be very complex and fraught with pitfalls, either do copious research or get an immigration attorney.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie: "You might even likely have committed immigration fraud" Nope. What he/she did was perfectly fine. It's perfectly fine to marry on a visit and then leave. Lots of foreigners hold their weddings in the US on a visit all the time, just like lots of Americans hold their weddings abroad on a visit.

Comment: @user102008 You're rushing to judgment. I said **might**. I am aware if one does not file an AOS immediately & opts for consular processing & returns home, at first blush it clears the issue of preconceived intent. Nevertheless there are scenarios  where immigration fraud could be construed. Including if she went for a visa knowing this marriage plan & did not reveal it during the interview when probed. I am simply alerting OP to be well informed and cover all the bases. Clearly OP needs some guidance. She's after all planning to return on F1 **and** stay while undergoing consular processing.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** use an F-1 visa unless you can demonstrate you no longer have a plan to live permanently in the USA. By your own statement:

> and got married there to a US citizen. Then I returned to the UK to
>   sort out finances while awaiting a spousal visa.

you have demonstrated [**immigration intent**](http://www.americanlaw.com/dintent.html) and hence are no longer qualified for an F-1 which is a visa type that requires you **do not** have immigration intent. It is not a dual intent visa, unlike the H-1 and L visas.

You will have to wait until your spousal visa comes through. If you choose to go for the F-1 visa and tell [untruths](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume8-PartJ-Chapter2.html) to the consular in order to get it, at any point in the future your permanent residency or even citizenship can be [revoked](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume12-PartL-Chapter2.html) for fraud/misrepresentation to an immigration officer which can lead to [removal](https://www.usa.gov/deportation) and most times a [permanent bar](https://www.shusterman.com/unlawfulpresencesimmigrationbars/) from coming to the USA. You don't want to go down that route.